# TFS command to get code from server

Tags: tfs

I am new to TFS and i have been using svn,mercury.

I am confused by the workspace, workload get commands

I need to get the code from the TFS server, where the URL and user credentials are given.

Please let me know the command to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Mac with tfs command line utility.

anyways, The below URL really helps

http://support.teamprise.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a tight integration with TFS throughout [Team Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181304.aspx) which provides you with a GUI allowing you to checkout projects from a TFS server, modify and check your changes back in to the server.